# Why is my supervised django celeryd process not accepting tasks?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, amqp, django-celery, supervisord

We've had a django-celery process with 5 worker processes running in production for ages now. It properly receives and runs tasks. These processes run tasks which are inserted into two queues: `live` and `celery`.

The command used to run the celery process is roughly:

```
manage.py celeryd -E --loglevel=WARNING --concurrency=5 \
         --settings=django_settings.production_celery -Q live,celery
```

I've now just built a new system which is supposed to process different tasks on a different queue called `foobar`. These celery processes are run with a command roughly like:

```
manage.py celeryd -E --loglevel=WARNING --concurrency=5 \
         --settings=django_settings.production_foobar -Q foobar
```

However when I attempt to run tasks in the new queue using `my_task.apply_async(queue='foobar')`, the result object remains in a `PENDING` state indefinitely.

Through logging I have determined that the `foobar` workers never receive the task. So now I'm trying to debug at what point the task message is being lost.

(We use RabbitMQ as our AMQP message broker.)

How can I determine the current contents of a celery queue? Can I directly inspect the contents of the RabbitMQ queue?